# Android Studio editor does not recognize changes in .aar dependency

Tags: android-studio

I have added a dependency to an .aar library in my Android project like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('/home/user1/Schreibtisch/data/code/Android/StandardLib/StandardLib/standardlib/build/outputs/aar/standardlib-debug.aar')
}
```

(The code is a piece of my app build.gradle. Not the project build.gradle.)

The problem is that the editor does not recognize new versions of my .aar library.

For example when I add a new class to the .aar library it won't be recognized by the editor. The editor says that the new class does not exist.
Android Studio must have cached an old version of the .aar library somewhere.

I tried "Build > Clean Project" and "Build > Rebuild Project" but it doesn't work.

I can successfully build and run my project. The only problem is the editor which does not recognize changes in the .aar library.

Any ideas?